# D3.js shade area between two lines using CSS fill

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

Pretty new to D3.js, I am able to achieve area below top line and area below bottom line, and have shaded these using fill.

[image]

Now i want to keep area below bottom line as transparent but area in between as shaded. How can i do so?

```
.areaBelow {
  fill: green;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.areaAbove {
  fill: lightsteelblue;
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10ueyt8n/)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901271/using-d3-to-shade-area-between-two-lines

Comment: @Mark That's a different implementation all together, I will have to change complete graph to achieve that, can I somehow achieve what I want using CSS?

Comment: I don't know a way with pure `CSS` but the changes are pretty easy.  I updated your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/10ueyt8n/1/).